# How can I mark a comment as the right answer?

Tags: support, comments, unanswered-questions

I have obtained an answer to my question which is in the comment. How can I mark it as the answer.
Please visit

[exchangelink](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49537/do-all-phy-ethernet-chips-have-a-hard-coded-mac-address)

WoutervanOoijen has given the correct answer to my question and I want to mark my question as answered but there is no Check(tick) option on the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't accept a comment as an answer. But you can suggest the author to change it in an answer, and then accept it.